# UICollectionViewLayout 'freezes'

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionviewlayout

I’m a swift/iOS noobie and I’m starting to think I’ve taken-on Everest as my first assignment. In any case, my app has a scrolling week-based calendar view. I’m using a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`. When the app starts up everything looks good and I can scroll down through the 24-hrs and right through the days (see first image).

[image: Layout on start-up]

When the user reaches the end of the predefined number of cells (days) more cells are added to the data source. I can happily scroll right continuously and the code adds more cells as required.

The problem:

When I stop scrolling through the days after any additional data (days) have been added to the data source, and then re-start scrolling the layout freezes in a single block and just floats around (see second image).

[image: 'Frozen' layout]

The correct placement (pinning) of cells to the top of the view no longer works (as its just the aforementioned frozen block of cells) and no new cells are displayed.

Curiously, after the layout freezes the terminal continues to log out debug from the `UICollectionViewLayout` placing the cells in the correct place although it seems the `UICollectionViewController` has just stopped listening?

Printed in the terminal for the ‘Date’ cell:  `Cell attributes: <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x6080003edf00> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0x60800003a760> {length = 2, path = 2 - 0}); frame = (1033 235; 47 50); zIndex = 1024;`

From the View Hierarchy debug: `(UICollectionView):   <UICollectionView: 0x7feb7302d000; frame = (0 0; 667 375); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000051490>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000000329a0>; contentOffset: {1033, 235}; contentSize: {2651, 910}> collection view layout: <V3.CDCLayout: 0x7feb7140f1a0>`

From the View Hierarchy debug for the ‘Date’ cell:  `<V3.CDCMonthCell: 0x7feb7410a690; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (1201.5 361; 47 50); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000035180>>`

[ UPDATE ]

Hi Rob - I tried stripping back my code and then also followed a couple of tutorials which all ended with the same problem when I add my data source (singleton) - so there's a hot suspect(!) but I just cant figure it. The code below is based on a tutorial example but exhibits the same issue.

CollectionViewController:

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "cCell"

class CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let localItems = Items.items.getItems()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 6  }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Items.items.getItemCount()
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if (Items.items.getItemCount() - indexPath.row ) == 2 {
            Items.items.addItems()
            collectionView.reloadData()
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CustomCollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = "SEC=\(indexPath.section),IXDI=\(indexPath.item)"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    let CELL_HEIGHT = 145.0
    let CELL_WIDTH = 145.0
    let STATUS_BAR = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    var cellAttrsDictionary = Dictionary<IndexPath, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>()
    var contentSize = CGSize.zero

    override var collectionViewContentSize : CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }

    override func invalidateLayout() {
        super.invalidateLayout()
        cellAttrsDictionary.removeAll()
    }

    override func prepare() {

        if (collectionView?.numberOfSections)! > 0 {
            for section in 0...collectionView!.numberOfSections-1 {

               if (collectionView?.numberOfItems(inSection: section))! > 0 {
                    for item in 0...collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section)-1 {

                        let cellIndex = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                        let xPos = Double(item) * CELL_WIDTH
                        let yPos = Double(section) * CELL_HEIGHT

                        let cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: cellIndex)
                        cellAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)

                        if section == 0 && item == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 4
                        } else if section == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 3
                        } else if item == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 2
                        } else {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 1
                        }

                        cellAttrsDictionary[cellIndex] = cellAttributes
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let contentWidth = Double(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) * CELL_WIDTH
        let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections) * CELL_HEIGHT
        self.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var attributesInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        for cellAttributes in cellAttrsDictionary.values {
            if rect.intersects(cellAttributes.frame) {
                attributesInRect.append(cellAttributes)
            }
        }
        return attributesInRect
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath]!
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Items/data-source/singleton:

```
class Items {

    static var items = Items() // Singleton

    var classItems = [Int]()

    init() {
        addItems()
    }

    func getItemCount() -> Int {
        return classItems.count
    }

    func getItems() -> [Int] {
        return classItems
    }

    func addItems() {
        for i in 1 ... 7 {
            classItems.append(i)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's going to be hard to diagnose this without code. I'd suggest you create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem and then post the image and code for for that MCVE. But there's not enough here for us to understand what went wrong and we definitely don't want to see all the code that produced these images. We need MCVE with code.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this Rob. Good suggestion on the MCVE. Let me do that.

Comment: BTW, if your collection view doesn't appear to be updating even though you have evidence that the app is not deadlocked, I'd keep an eye out for any accidental UI updates from a background thread (either something you manually dispatched to a background queue or something in a `URLSession` completion handler, which runs on a background queue). Make sure you don't have any `reloadData` or similar calls on any background threads.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Everything thus far should be on the main thread.

Comment: Rob - I updated with a code MCVE. Hopefully you'll be able to figure this :o)

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, the reloading of the data source in `willDisplay` seemed to be the root of the problem. By `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` the problems seemed to go away.

```
private var lastReloadedRow = 0

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (Items.items.getItemCount() - indexPath.row) == 2 && lastReloadedRow < indexPath.row {
        lastReloadedRow = indexPath.row
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            Items.items.addItems()
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I added a state property to keep track of whether we already loaded because the way it was, it was reloading multiple times unnecessarily.

---

For the sake of completeness, here is my complete implementation of your custom layout. I did a few unrelated things:

- Simplified [`layoutAttributesForElements(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionviewlayout/1524636-layoutattributesforelements); and
- Turned off [`shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionviewlayout/1531047-shouldinvalidatelayout) because you were rebuilding your dictionary more than necessary.

Thus:

```
class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    let CELL_HEIGHT = 145.0
    let CELL_WIDTH = 145.0
    let STATUS_BAR = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    var cellAttrsDictionary = Dictionary<IndexPath, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>()
    var contentSize = CGSize.zero

    override var collectionViewContentSize : CGSize {
        return contentSize
    }

    override func invalidateLayout() {
        super.invalidateLayout()
        cellAttrsDictionary.removeAll()
    }

    override func prepare() {
        if collectionView!.numberOfSections > 0 {
            for section in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfSections {
                if collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) > 0 {
                    for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
                        let cellIndex = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)
                        let xPos = Double(item) * CELL_WIDTH
                        let yPos = Double(section) * CELL_HEIGHT

                        let cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: cellIndex)
                        cellAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)

                        cellAttrsDictionary[cellIndex] = cellAttributes
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let contentWidth = Double(collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)) * CELL_WIDTH
        let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections) * CELL_HEIGHT
        contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        return cellAttrsDictionary.values.filter { $0.frame.intersects(rect) }
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath]!
    }

    // override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
    //     return true
    // }
}
```

Comment: Protocol seems to preclude thanks; but hey - credit where its due - great work. Good pick-up on the additional tuning.